# If I have two random variables $X,Y$, if $(X-Y) \geq 0$, is it true that $E((X-Y)^2) \geq 0$?

Tags: probability-theory

If I have two random variables $X,Y$, such that  $(X-Y)^2 \geq 0$ (trivially true), is it true that $E((X-Y)^2) \geq 0$? The problem I am having is that if I split up the quadratic term, $E((X-Y)^2) = E(X^2-2XY+Y^2) = E(X^2) -2E(XY) + E(Y^2)$, is there a chance the middle term of $-2E(XY)$ can dominate the two terms on the outside and hence make it so that my expectation is negative? Thanks

Comment: It is true. An expectation is an integral. An integral is monotone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a nonnegative random variable then $EX$ is always nonnegative. Indeed, $$EX = \int  X dP$$

must be nonnegative since $P$ is a nonnegative measure and $X$ is nonnegative. An alternative formula is $$EX=\int  P(X>t)dt$$

and since $X\geqslant 0$ this integral involves only $t>0$, so it must be nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

No need to split up the terms. For any random variable $Z$, if $Z\ge0$ then $Z^2\ge0$, and therefore $E(Z^2)\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows by the [monotonicity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Monotonicity) (or integration):

If $M \le N$, then $E[M] \le E[N]$

Choose $M = 0$ and $N = (X-Y)^2$, and the desired result follows (assuming of course $E[M]$ and $E[N]$ exist).